# Vector graphics library for Windows with C# bindings

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, vector-graphics

For fun, I'd like to see if I can create a library that is a bit like a small subset of WPF: a managed template driven vector based graphics system. (I have some theories I'd like to test.) I am not however a graphics genius and am looking for a good vector graphics library to start with.

I know Microsoft uses MilCore internally which more or less seems to pass a list of vector structures from the managed world to the unmanaged world and renders them. I believe this underlying library is immediate mode based. I'd like to use an existing free vector graphics library with a laundry list of desired features:

1. Vector based
2. Immediate or retained mode, preferably immediate?
3. Pixel shader support
4. Geometry hit testing would be nice
5. Image support, image rotation support
6. .NET binding
7. Stable to the point of being commercially viable on a small scale

Things I don't need:

1. Cross platform support. If that locks it into DirectX or even Direct3D 10 or 11 specifically, so be it.
2. Higher level management of graphics in anything resembling a "control". This layer of management I'd probably want to do myself.
3. I'm not scared of a little interop.
4. Super awesome performant. I'd like this to be performant but if usability suffers too much because of it, I won't be successful.

This library http://jeremiahmorrill.com/2011/02/05/a-simple-directcanvas-tutorial/ looks similar to what I'd like, but preferably something more stable and with more examples.
I'd prefer something a layer above DX/OpenGL if possible.

What options do I have? Does this exist or is it just a pipe dream? Thank you in advance - I feel like I've just typed in a shopping list but I'd really appreciate the community's feedback on this. It didn't quite seem to fit other vector graphics questions I've seen listed here, but if I missed a great post, let me know!

Comment: I've been searching for something similar for a while now, but without luck. I hope someone could find it, but it seems more like the search for the Holy grail :) There are direct wrappers to DirectX, but that is a no go, then there is DirectCanvas but it is not exactly what I need...

Comment: I took a look at Clutter but couldn't find any up to date .NET bindings. Any comments on Clutter?

Answer (score 3):

I worked several times with [VG.NET](http://vgdotnet.com/) library. It's realy easy to use, has great designer and the images and animations are fast. It's my best recommendation.

Comment: This looks not so far to what I'm looking for but I'm worried that... well, it looks a little dated. It's GDI+ based. I'm guessing that kind of rules out shader support too. Thanks though! It's nice not to be pointed to something not so low level.

Comment: Yes, it is build on GDI+, but the performance is really great. They did very much optimizations.

Comment: Regarding VG.net, I am a developer, and we are working on a Direct2D port. I cannot say when it will be released yet. You should be able to switch between Direct2d and GDI+ using the same libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I've used Cairo before for vector graphics. It's a great library to get started with (cross platform, many language bindings, open-source, etc).

You can check out the language bindings here:

http://cairographics.org/bindings/

I've used these .NET/Mono bindings (by NDesk) with great success:

http://git.ndesk.org/?p=cairo-sharp

Comment: According to this page there is a OpenGL backend: http://cairographics.org/backends/

Comment: The OpenGL backend is pretty great. I used it once for accelerated textual transformations for a fun text-editor project I was working on. Very neat.

Comment: Here's a post I found on Cairo, OpenGL, and C#: http://majkel.wordpress.com/2007/04/26/using-cairo-opengl-and-c/

Answer (score 0):

You can try SlimDX http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SlimDX - they have Direct2D and DirectX wrappers. I believe both of them will cover your requirements.

Comment: 1. Direct2D was antiqued for Dirext3D because of hardware support (you just do 2d in 3d now from what I remember) 2. SlimDX isn't really a Vector library. It's rasterization engine can do similar things, but not quite the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can see Mono + Open GL that will give you power of .NET and Open GL, but you will have to get in depth with open gl to build your library but this will ensure platform independence.

http://www.opentk.com/

http://www.mono-project.com/Tao

I have not tried any one of them myself yet, but looking at samples, they seem pretty easy to begin with. Having done on Open GL will be useful in future as even mobile devices like iPhone now comes with support for Open GL.

Comment: I'd really prefer to stay out of the underlying graphical framework as much as possible. I'd like to work something more at a Geometry object level rather than vertices - does this support that kind of level or am I going to get down into the nitty gritty details for drawing trapezoids?